# Are there any proofs for (ir)rationality of the numbers $\sin(e)$, $\cos(e)$?

Tags: rationality-testing

Are there any proofs for the (ir)rationality of the numbers $\sin(e)$, $\cos(e)$, $\tan(e)$, and $\cot(e)$?
Thanking in advance for any references.

Comment: This may be related to the algebraic independence of $\pi$ and $e$.

Comment: As a complete outsider to the field, I would guess that the transcendence of special constructs like these is completely unknown.